# Somehow the method replace(Item, int) is undefined for the type Map<Item,Integer>. Shortly i dont understand what is causing that error,

Tags: java

```
public class Stock {
Map<Item, Integer> items = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
```

Receiving items in stock

```
public void receive(Order order) throws OrderRejectedException {
    Iterator<OrderDetail> iter = order.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        OrderDetail orderDetail = iter.next();
        Item item = orderDetail.getItem();
        validate(orderDetail);
```

If item is in stock then increase existing amount

```
        Integer qty = orderDetail.getQty();
        if (items.containsKey(item)) {
```

Error is coming in from here

```
            items.replace(item, items.get(item) + qty); // The method replace(Item, int) is undefined for the type Map<Item,Integer>
        } else {
            // If it is not in stock then add
            items.put(item, qty);
            transactions.add(new Transaction(item, qty, order, "Receive"));
        }
    }
}
```

Error is coming in `items.replace(item, items.get(item) + qty);`
What i should change? Method `replace`is Item , int as it is set for `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

When you put something in a `HashMap` which is already present it becomes overwritten.

Therefore, just `HashMap#put` does exactly what your meessing `HashMap#replace` function would do.

**Example**

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> i = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
i.put(1, 1);
i.put(2, 2);
System.out.println(i);
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e : i.entrySet())
    i.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + 1);
System.out.println(i);
```

**Output**

```
{1=1, 2=2}
{1=2, 2=3}
```

Comment: Super Niels! it is working fine. Looks like put is my new lifesaver ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
Item value = items.get(item);
items.put(item, value + qty);
```

This will overwrite the existing entry.

Comment: He can still write a one-liner if he wants: `items.put(item, items.get(item) + qty);`

Answer (score 0):

I have just expermimented with my code to see any issues

```
Map<Item, Integer> map = new HashMap<Item, Integer>(){
            {
                put(new Item(1, "burger"), 1);
            }
        };
        map.replace(new Item(1, "burger"), (2+1));
        System.out.println(map.get(new Item(1, "burger")));
```

and my Item Class implementation is as follows

```
public class Item {
    public Item(Integer itemId, String itemName){
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    private Integer itemId;
    private String itemName;
    public Integer getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(Integer itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.itemId+this.itemName.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Item otherItem = (Item) obj;
        if(this.itemId.equals(otherItem.getItemId()) && this.getItemName().equals(otherItem.getItemName())){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I hope that helps, I am using java 8 version are you getting the same?
If possible can you enclose the screen shot of the error of the ide?